# DataContract Serializer and Json.Net When using object that contains property of type XmlElement

Tags: c#, json, serialization, signalr

We currently have an object what we are using to pass around information about incoming API calls of of the properties is the message itself. The message property is an XmlElement and the DataContract serializer is happy to do it's thing with an XmlElement.

We are no adding on to our API and these web services are making RPC via SignalR to hosted clients across the united states. What I have found is that the Json.Net library is not happy with an XmlElement I get the following message "Xmlnodeconverter only supports deserializing xml document". Okay fine so I'll use an XmlDocument then and get around this problem... But wait the DataContract Serailizer isn't happy with an XmlDocument. It seems to be a situation where I cant have my cake and eat it too. If I go with XmlDocument the SignalR client is happy but the rest of the applications are not, and if I use a XmlElement the SignlR client can't recive the message.

Note: the SignalR client is a self hosted windows service not javascript.

So what I want to know is. Is there a way to either get Json.net to except XmlElement or the DataContract Serializer to except XmlDocument. It would be much simpler for us to change the SignalR side of things as this is new and the rest of the applications alrady understand the XmlElement.

Here is the object that contains the XmlElement:

```
  [DataContract(Name = "AuditData")]
  public class AuditData
  {
[DataMember]
public XmlElement Message { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public XmlDocument MessageV2 { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public IList<ErrorMessage> Errors { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string DealerCode { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public IntegrationTransactionTypeEnum TransationType { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string BooksAccountNumber { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public IntegrationStepIdEnum Step { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public IntegrationErrorLevelEnum? ErrorLevel { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public IEnumerable<Criteria> Search { get; set; }
```

}